# Updating User Document and Suddenly Unable to Log In Node, Express, Mongoose

Tags: express, validation, mongoose, model

First StackOverflow post, so here I go: I am creating a blog for my friends. Users can log in, post, and update their profiles. After implementing a basic user document (user profile) update, which still has other kinks to work out, something more heinous has occurred. I can no longer log in using the same credentials. I have tried removing the ability to update username because I thought it is the only logical thing tied to that user's ability to log in, however even updating the image/bio will result in the user being unable to log in.

Here is my updateProfile()

```
exports.updateProfile = async (req, res, next) => {

    var image = req.files.image;
    const data = {};

    if (req.body.username === '' || undefined) {
        delete req.body.username;
    } else {
        data.username = req.body.username.trim();
    }

    if (req.body.email === '' || undefined) {
        delete req.body.email;
    } else {
        data.email = req.body.email.trim();
    }

    if (req.body.bio === '' || undefined) {
        delete req.body.bio;
    } else {
        data.bio = req.body.bio.trim();
    }

    let user = await User.findById(req.session.userID);

    if (!data.username === false) {
        await user.updateOne({ username: data.username });
    }
    if (!data.email === false) await user.updateOne({ email: data.email });
    if (!data.bio === false) await user.updateOne({ bio: data.bio });
    if (image) {
        image.mv(
            path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'public/img', image.name),
            async (error) => {
                await user.updateOne({ image: '/img/' + image.name });
            }
        );
    }

    const updatedUser = await User.findById(req.session.userID);
    user = updatedUser;

    user.save(function () {
        res.render('profile', {
            user,
        });
    });
};
```

Here is my User Model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
const validator = require('validator');

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please provide username.'],
        unique: true,
        minlength: [2, 'Name must be longer than one character.'],
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please provide a email.'],
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        validate: [validator.isEmail, 'Please provide a valid email'],
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please provide password.'],
        minlength: [2, 'Password must be longer than eight characters.'],
    },
    image: {
        type: String, //PATH IN FILE SYSTEM WHERE IMAGE IS UPLOADED
        default: '/img/default-user-image.png',
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['Neophyte', 'admin'],
        default: 'Neophyte',
    },
    bio: {
        type: String,
        default: `Tell us about yourself...`,
    },
});

UserSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    const user = this;
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, (error, hash) => {
        user.password = hash;
        next();
    });
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Now literally as I'm writing this, I believe that the UserSchema.pre('save')... is the culprit. However, because I have written this much and would like to hear from the community on what they think is recommended solutions or tell me I'm way off, let me know! Is the bcrypt re-encrypting over the password again causing a lockout?

Best!

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the password is modified or not and hash it only when it's modiefied using [.isModified()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-isModified)

```js
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    const user = this;
    if (user.isModified('password')) {
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, (error, hash) => {
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance!